# Get human readable name of extension point contributor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I get human readable name from `IConfigurationElement`? I've found out that I can use `lement.getDeclaringExtension().getDeclaringPluginDescriptor().getLabel()` however the last two methods are marked as deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Do you want the name of the `IConfigurationElement` itself? Or the name of the plug-in that declared it? Or ... ? There are a lot of `getName()` methods in that neighborhood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name of the declaring plugin (the Bundle-Name in the MANIFEST.MF) use:

```java
IConfigurationElement element = ...

String contributorName = element.getContributor().getName();

Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(contributorName);

String bundleName = bundle.getHeaders().get("Bundle-Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say element is IConfigurationElement '
then `element.getContributor().getName()`